# Application for tracking applications usage times

Tags: linux, gnome, time, application, productivity

Does there exist a program which allows to automatically track "window focus" time in, for example, Gnome? For example, I would like to track how much time per day I spend using a certain chat application.

Comment: Yes, certain chat applications implement logging.

Comment: @CinaedSimson Can you please give a specific example?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chat_log. I don't use them I just know of them.

Comment: @CinaedSimson As far as I can see, a chat log is just a text log. I'm interested in logging application window titles and the related times of usage.